# How to know you got no result from the database

Tags: c#, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to test if a DataSet is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976473/how-to-test-if-a-dataset-is-empty)

I'm executing these lines

```
string commToExc = @"SELECT * FROM Test WHERE id = 500;";
MySqlCommand cmdSQL = new MySqlCommand(commToExc, conMYSQL);
MySqlDataAdapter zipcode = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL);
DataSet setTest = new DataSet("Test");
```

I'm taking data by their rows id.
everthing works fine, i get the results i want but i have question.
For example in db `id` = [1-500]. But i request row with id = 501 and i get 0 results back. 
Whats is the way to know when I got 0 results? Thnx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (setTest.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess at some point you will fill the DS something like the below:

```
zipcode.Fill(setTest );
```

Then you can simply check how may rows have been returned using the `Count` property of the `Rows` collection on the DT

Answer (score 0):

you must fill the DataSet,or the DataSet is empty