# How to check a value in dataset is empty or not?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, file-upload, dataset

I have a fileupload option in my project. It inclueds a query which returns a dataset. It works fine. But now i want to check whether the returning dataset is is empty or the same value i passed as a parameter to the query. Here is my back end code.

**.cs code**

```
if ((FileUpload1.HasFile))//&& (ext == ".pdf")
{
    ds = db.checkExistingPDF(fileName);
    if (dbFileName != fileName)
    {
         this.FileUpload1.SaveAs(Path.Combine(svrPath, fileName + ".pdf"));
         ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Message", " alert('Successfully uploaded');", true);                    
    }
    else
    {
         ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Message", " confirm ('Appeal is availbale for the this competition') ; ", true);  
    }    
else
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Message", " confirm ('Error') ; ", true);
}
```

Here is my query

```
public DataSet checkExistingPDF(string fileName)
{
    string strQuery = @"IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM APPEAL_MASTER WHERE Attachment_upload = '"+ fileName +"')";

    return SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(strConnStringAppeal, CommandType.Text, strQuery);
}
```

Comment: Isn't it answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976473/how-to-test-if-a-dataset-is-empty?rq=1)?

Comment: ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count

Comment: @jakub most import condition to check the input parameter exist in the database already. to check it's empty or not is optional

Comment: @vivek kv I want to check dataset reurns same value which was in the parameter too. It has the highest priority

Comment: string strQuery = @"IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM APPEAL_MASTER WHERE Attachment_upload = '"+ fileName +"')".. query is incorrect.. Isn't it return an error?. it should be string strQuery = @"SELECT * FROM APPEAL_MASTER WHERE Attachment_upload = '"+ fileName +"'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check dataset is empty or not You have to check null and tables count.

```
Dataset ds=checkExistingPDF("filename");
if(ds != null && ds.Tables.count > 0)
{
 // your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Get your result in **dataset object** and then validate for **NULL and table row count**:

```
Dataset ds=checkExistingPDF("filename");
if (ds != null && ds.Tables.Count > 0 && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    //record exist with same filename
}
else
{
    //no any record exist with same filename
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DataSet dsReturnedObj = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(strConnStringAppeal, CommandType.Text, strQuery);
return dsReturnedObj == null ? null : dsRetunredObj
```

In your code behind cs file:

```
Dataset dsReturnedObj = db.checkExistingPDF(fileName)
if (dsReturnedObj != null)
{
     if (dsReturnedObj.Tables.Count > 0)
     {
         if (dsReturnedObj.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
         {
             this.FileUpload1.SaveAs(Path.Combine(svrPath, fileName + ".pdf"));
             ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Message", " alert('Successfully uploaded');", true);
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: @ Balagurunathan Please if you can add the code to check the returning value and the parameter value is same or not

Comment: @user6592730 the above code returns the empty dataset if your parameter doesn't match.

Comment: Yes I know. But i want to compare the reurn value with the filename to know whether it already exists or not

Comment: the query `string strQuery = @"IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM APPEAL_MASTER WHERE Attachment_upload = '"+ fileName +"')";` obviously returns the dataset with table and record in it; if file name contains in the table. Then why need to check again??