# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Select'. how to resolve in this code

Tags: sql, asp.net, ado.net

This code is throwing an error on the line marked below, can anyone point me in the right direction to why this is throwing an error?

```
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalSqlServer"].ConnectionString);
    SqlDataAdapter dadapter;
    DataSet dset; 
    string sql = "SELECT * from  SocoetyMaintan";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            dadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
            dset = new DataSet();
            dadapter.Fill(dset);
            DropDownList1.DataSource = dset.Tables[0];
            DropDownList1.DataTextField = "FullName";
            DropDownList1.DataValueField = "Id";
            DropDownList1.DataBind();
            GridViewBind();
        }
    }
      protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GridViewBind();
        }
        public void GridViewBind()
        {
            dadapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * from SocoetyMaintan where Id=" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "", con);
            dset = new DataSet(); //Throwing Error Here
            dadapter.Fill(dset);
            GridView1.DataSource = dset.Tables[0];
            GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Use prepared statements.  What is the type of the `Id` column in your table, and what C# type are you trying to bind to it?

Comment: When you say error - do you mean compilation time error?

Comment: Error simply means that Select statement format is incorrect, it cannot be parsed, why can't you just figure out  the Select statement generated and whether it would run as plain sql or not, that's the whole issue

Comment: try this => `dadapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * from SocoetyMaintan where Id='" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "'", con);`

Comment: Did you open the SQL connection anywhere in your code?

Comment: No, where exactly i need to open that?

Comment: @Poojakulkarni, did u try my above commented code?

Comment: yes i tried this as well it says "The DataSourceID of 'GridView1' must be the ID of a control of type IDataSource.  A control with ID 'GridDataSource' could not be found"

Comment: try to set your `asp:GridView` => `DataSourceID="GridDataSource"` and `asp:SqlDataSource` => `ID="GridDataSource"` and keep my previous commented code as it is and let me know.

Comment: Its working !!!!   thank you!! @ershoaib

Comment: so can i add this as answer to yuor question? then u just mark tick beside the answer

Comment: yes you can! surely i will tick, as you know i am new here...just let me know where exactly

Comment: @Poojakulkarni, I added my answer, you just seen tickmark at left side of answer :) you just need to tick to make it green

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Just try to change your query like below

```
dadapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * from SocoetyMaintan where Id='" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "'", con);
```

**Note:** Better to use prepared statements to your query.

```
dadapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * from SocoetyMaintan where Id=@Id", con);
dadapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
```

2)  Try to set your `asp:GridView` => `DataSourceID="GridDataSource"` and `asp:SqlDataSource` => `ID="GridDataSource"`

Comment: @Poojakulkarni, view the answer might be it help you :)

Comment: Hello Sir, need one more help , in the above code I want to add iff statement for  GridViewBind() where in the else case i want to say "NO DATA TO DISPLAY"  so how to write such if statement condition?  @ershoiab

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976473/how-to-test-if-a-dataset-is-empty

Answer (score 0):

Here, you forgot to convert `DropDownList1.SelectedValue` to string or int whatever in your database. So do it as follow.
For example,

```
dadapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from SocoetyMaintan where Id='" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString() + "';", con);
```

Comment: DropDownList1.SelectedValue is of type string FYI

Comment: I don't understand what you say "FYI". Plz say it again.

Comment: Okay. Got it. ';' is missing in query.

Comment: @ksdev nope `;` is not necessary for a single query and won't have any effect in here.

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani yeah. I accept that but its good practice to use it. It will effect while wrting multiple queries.

Comment: after pasting above soln query it says " Incorrect syntax near 'dfg;'." at same line @ksdev nope

Comment: @Poojakulkarni Now try again. I have changed it. If its not work then tell me what is DropDownList1? like ComboBox, etc.

Comment: DropDownList1 it  DropDownList like comboBox you can say

Comment: @Poojakulkarni Then you can use DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString() method it will work.

Comment: @Poojakulkarni You are missing ' at start and at end also in your original query.

Comment: @Poojakulkarni You are welcome.. Its working or not?

Answer (score 0):

It think you're missing quotes in `Id=`.

```
 $"SELECT * from SocoetyMaintan where Id='{DropDownList1.SelectedValue}';"
```

BTW. You should never allow direct input from user into your queries. Look up 'SQL injection'.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are writing may give error. Try the following

**Method 1:**

```
SqlDataAdapter dadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(string.Format("SELECT * FROM SocoetyMaintan WHERE Id = '{0}'",DropDownList1.SelectedValue), con);
```

**Method 2:** (Preferred)

```
using (SqlDataAdapter dadapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM SocoetyMaintan WHERE Id = @id", con))
{
    int filter = ID;
    dadapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
}
```

Comment: Have you heard about Little Bobby Tables? https://xkcd.com/327/ People should be punished for Method 1. :)

Comment: What will happen if DropDownList1.SelectedValue equals to something like that "1';Drop table SocoetyMaintan;'1'='1"